# Twitter-bootstrap form not getting responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this contact but it doesn't seems to be responsive when I change browser size or browse it via my cell.
When I open it on my cell or resize my browser window the input area gets too smaller than expected.

**My Code:**

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="well span8" action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" type="text" name="name" required>

                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" value="" type="text" name="email" required>

                <label>Subject</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
                    <option selected value="na">
                        Choose One:
                    </option>

                    <option value="query">
                        Query
                    </option>

                    <option value="suggestions">
                        Suggestions
                    </option>

                    <option value="advertise">
                        Advertise
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <label>Message</label> 
                <textarea class="form-control" required id="message" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>

        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Can You Please tell me how to make it responsive.

Comment: You've mixed Bootstrap `2.3` & `3.*` here, which one are you using? Secondly, switch `xs-*` to `md-*` Take a look at [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Can You please fix this in answer ?

Comment: a lot of the responsiveness comes from css errors. Show us the css.

Comment: I have not used any external css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way ( one in many )

Use `col-sm-xx` instead of `col-xs-xx` give a better result

**Bootply** :http://www.bootply.com/123382

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="well col-sm-8 " action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" type="text" name="name" required="">

                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" value="" type="text" name="email" required="">

                <label>Subject</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
                    <option selected="" value="na">
                        Choose One:
                    </option>

                    <option value="query">
                        Query
                    </option>

                    <option value="suggestions">
                        Suggestions
                    </option>

                    <option value="advertise">
                        Advertise
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label>Message</label> 
                <textarea class="form-control" required="" id="message" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>

        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE FATER COMMENT**:

Use first `col-sm-12` instead `col-sm/xs-8` :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123389

Comment: Maybe the first col-sm-8 is optionnal... and can stay with col-xs-8

Answer (score 1):

use bootstraps classes `.col-xs-` `.col-sm-` `.col-md-` and `.col-lg-` to make it responsive for different devices you can see example here

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

i have created a  very simple example, i think it will help u.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><input style="width:100%" type="text"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><input style="width:100%" type="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Working**

http://www.bootply.com/123390